# ACF - getfield() returns blank value

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I got this WP installed with ACF
Got a problem that getfield returns blank value.

Heres my Code in front-page.php

```
<?php
        $forside_slagord_stor = get_field('forside_slagord_stor');
        $forside_slagord_liten = get_field('forside_slagord_liten');
        $forside_slagord_liter = get_field('om_oss_tekst');
?>
    <header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="intro-text">
            <div class="intro-lead-in"><?php echo $forside_slagord_stor;?></div>
            <div class="intro-heading"><?php echo $forside_slagord_liter;?></div>
            <a href="#services" class="page-scroll btn btn-xl">Tell Me More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Here is my ACF setup.
[image: ACF setup]

And here is ACF - forside setup
[image: ACF - forside setup]

The result is that it returns empty value .

Thank you for your help

Comment: I think the code is correct! maybe you can try ' -> "" in the php part but i guess that is not the problem

Comment: Make sure you are on current post. If not you have to specify post id as 2nd param. `get_field($field_name, $post_id);`

Comment: Thank you for your answers. iam pretty sure that iam on the current post. Could it be that i need to require som acf files before this code fires? or could it be that iam developing on localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the second parameter in get_field, you need to be in the loop, and it's seems that you are not in.

If your code is at the top of the page, you need to add the post ID parameter, you need to use the `global $post;` to get it.

```
<?php
    global $post;

    $forside_slagord_stor = get_field('forside_slagord_stor', $post->ID);
    $forside_slagord_liten = get_field('forside_slagord_liten', $post->ID);
    $forside_slagord_liter = get_field('om_oss_tekst', $post->ID);
?>
<header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="intro-text">
        <div class="intro-lead-in"><?php echo $forside_slagord_stor;?></div>
        <div class="intro-heading"><?php echo $forside_slagord_liter;?></div>
        <a href="#services" class="page-scroll btn btn-xl">Tell Me More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another answer about one of your comment : you don't need to include any file of acf, when the template is about to render, all the plugins files and assets are usually load.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you Sir. Your answer was very helpful.  At first i there was no page "connected to front page, so post_id was blank. Than i set "forside" to static front page. Than it worked like a charm. Thank you very much!